# Why i can't import mediapipe in Python 3.12.1?

Tags: python, importerror, mediapipe, python-3.12

I use Python 3.12.1.
I'm Trying to import(install) Mediapipe but can't.
The Command i'm trying is

```
pip install mediapipe
```

```
python -m pip install mediapipe
```

```
python -m pip install mediapipe,whl
```

but all i get is errors after errors.

ScreenShot Attached.

System Details :

- OS Platform and Distribution (Windows 11 Home).
- Programming Language and Versions ( Python 3.12.1)
- Mediapipe Version (0.8.11. and 0.10.10.)
- 

The Command i'm trying is

```
pip install mediapipe
```

```
python -m pip install mediapipe
```

```
python -m pip install mediapipe,whl
```

Expecting Mediapipe to be installed and Run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

[Mediapipe doesn't support python 3.12](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/setup_python#supported_platforms_and_versions) yet.

You'll have to install Python 3.11 to be able to install and use mediapipe.

Answer (score 0):

Currently mediapipe only supports till **python 3.11** as tensorflow only support till python 3.11 for now.

> These flexible tools are built on top of TensorFlow Lite for the best end-to-end on-device ML and hardware performance.

##### You need to use python 3.11 to install mediapipe successfully

---

[image]

**https://developers.google.com/mediapipe**

**https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/**